# unable to launch emulator in android studio in VDI machine

Tags: android, android-emulator, appium

Android studio unable to launch emulator in VDI machine.
HAXM installation error issue.To solve it we need to enable virtualization in BIOS which is not possible in VDI machine. So how to launch emulator

Comment: Why are you trying run an emulator in an emulator?

Comment: android studio launches an emulator to run mobile apps. i need to work on it

Comment: I don't think you can run any emulator in a VDI. Mount a physical device via USB or install Android Studio on the host machine

Comment: any alternatives to work in VDI

Comment: Yes, I just said to mount a physical Android device... Basically, you're asking how to run a VDI in a VDI. It's not possible for your processor to run two emulation stacks

Comment: Did you figure out the solution, I am running through the same problem.

Comment: @cricket_007 problem here is we have to install and use the android studio from virtual machine for whatever reasons now here when we want to build and run the app we cant on android emulator as haxm is not supported on the virtual machine and other option left is to run the app by connecting device through USB,  now device is not shown in connected devices as virtual machine doesn't detect the USB devices I believe